# Rename gps-navigation to be gnss-navigation

Tags: discussion, tagging

Essentially all questions currently tagged [gps-navigation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps-navigation) are not specific to GPS, but apply to all GNSS, including GPS, GLONASS, Galileo, and others.  Many users may not even be aware which one of those technologies the GNSS in their device supports.  Therefore, I propose to rename the tag [gps-navigation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps-navigation) to a more appropriate [gnss-navigation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss-navigation) (or just [gnss](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss)), and make [gps-navigation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps-navigation) a synonym thereof.

Answer (score 12):

As most users seem not aware of the difference and GPS has become the general word for satellite navigation in a fair part of the world, I do not agree with the change.
We can make the new tag and see how often people select it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm well aware of the different satellite constellations, who launched them and why GNSS is different from GPS, yet I routinely use GPS to refer to any part of the system in any context except where the more detailed knowledge is appropriate. It's the commonly accepted term where I live, and would be the first term I'd search for unless I was looking for, say, GloNass, or Galileo in which case I'd search for those, and still not use GNSS.

We should leave things alone.